# Qt mousemoveevent + Qt::LeftButton

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsscene

Quick question, why does:

```
void roiwindow::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{ 
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    qDebug() << event->button();
}
```

return 0 instead of 1 when I'm holding down the left mouse button while moving the cursor around in a graphicscene. Is there anyway to get this to return 1 so I can tell when a user is dragging the mouse across the graphicscene. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Though Spyke's answer is correct, you can just use `buttons()` ([docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#buttons)).  `button()` returns the mouse button that *caused* the event, which is why it returns `Qt::NoButton`; but `buttons()` returns the buttons held down when the event was fired, which is what you're after.

Answer (score 10):

You can know if the left button was pressed by looking at the `buttons` property:

```
if ( e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton ) 
{
  // left button is held down while moving
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Ah, I read cbambers response first but I appreciate the post.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value is always Qt::NoButton for [mouse move events](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#button). You can use Event filter to solve this.

Try this

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *e)
{

 if (e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress && QApplication::mouseButtons()==Qt::LeftButton)
 {
  leftbuttonpressedflag=true;
 }

  if (e->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
 {
   QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e);
   if(leftbuttonpressedflag && mouseEvent->pos()==Inside_Graphics_Scene)
   qDebug("MouseDrag On GraphicsScene");
 }

 return false;

}
```

And also don't forget to install this event filter in mainwindow.

```
qApplicationobject->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even though this isnt the simplest solution I'm still going to look at how eventFilters work just in case I need it for some other potential problem I have. Thanks again.